# laravel - Ajax Post says NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. Recently I cloned sample project from github. I try to do curd operation. when I post the data I get

```
{"error":"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException","message":"","file":"\/home\/sq1\/lampstack-5.5.28\/apache2\/htdocs\/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/RouteCollection.php","line":145}}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group
(
    [
        'prefix'    => '/executive/ajax',
    ],
    function ()
    {
        Route::get
        (
            'get-executive',
            'LeadExecutiveController@getLeadExecutives'
        );
        Route::get
        (
            'get-executive/{sponsorID}',
            'LeadExecutiveController@getLeadExecutiveData'
        );
);
Route::resource('/executive' ,'ExecutiveController');
```

**ExecutiveController.php**

```
public function store() //I think store action should work here
{
 ...
}
public function destroy($id)
{
 ...
}
public function getLeadExecutiveData($leadExecutiveID)
{
 ...
}
public function update($leadExecutiveID)
{
 ...
}
```

**Ajax Url** : http://localhost:8080/app/public/deal/executive

**Post parameters:**

```
_token  : WXv5u4zYkANnnWidTciFN8HVrz2ARECe669Kwvqn
first_name : test
last_name  : test
```

Comment: I don't think your Url is properly built... how did you made it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting to **deal/executive**, but your resource set to **executive**.
Change your router to:

```
Route::resource('deal/executive' ,'ExecutiveController');
```

Comment: Remember to run: php artisan route:cache